# ストアドプロシージャのOUTPUT Parameterを受け取りたい

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework

Visual Studio2013のc#でAPIを開発しています。

StoredProcedureを使って、テーブルのデータをSelectしようと思いますが、
検索されたデータをC#のコードでどう持ってくるのかわかりません。
ObjectParameterを使ってはいますが、System.InvalidOperationException: The type parameter 'System.String' in ExecuteFunction is incompatible～というエラーが発生しています。
エラーを検索してコードを直しようと思いましたが、特に異常はありませんでした。
で、自分がObjectParameterの使用法を間違っているのではないかと思いますので
ObjectParameterの使用法をコードで教えていただきたいです。
また、プロシージャでSelectした結果をリストで持ってくることができますでしょうか？
例えば「名前が「カ」で始まり、背が160以上の人」と検索して傑作結果が10件以上出ました。
この結果をどう持ってきますか？

ちなみにMysqlを使っています。

Comment: 質問そのものに一旦は答えましたが、そもそもとしてEntity Frameworkを使いたいのでしょうか？ その上で、Entity Framework上でストアドプロシージャを呼び出したいのでしょうか？ アプローチが間違っているかもしれません。

Comment: @sayuri 　すでにEntity Data Modelを作成して、ストアドプロシージャを使っています。
ObjectParameterでResult値を持ってくるのはもうできました。
欲しいのはリストをResultで持ってくることです。

Answer (score 3):

[IN および OUT パラメーターとストアド プロシージャを使用してクエリを実行する方法](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb896334(v=vs.100).aspx)を参考にしてください。
もちろんパラメーターを複数持たせることは可能です。